# Как сделать исходник С++ приложения плохочитабельным?

Tags: криптография, шифрование, c++

Здравствуйте!

Есть исходный код, написанный на C++.
Нужно сделать его плохочитабельным, малочитабельным, главное чтобы человек не мог или же с трудом мог понять что там творится.
 Думаю что есть программы в которые вставляешь код, а она меняет переменным имена, убирает коменты... Вообщем делает нечитабельный для человека "кусок".

Кто знает нечто подобное? Быстрая замена не вариант.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перепишите на boost, и шаблонов побольше добавьте :)

А если по делу, то вам нужна [Обфускация](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что надо!

Answer (score 2):

Хм, интересно, зачем? Может, проще не давать исходник тем, кто их видеть не должен? Всё-таки это не JavaScript и даже не C#, где исходники можно получить почти в первозданном виде. Ну а вообще насколько понимаю, то, что вам нужно, называется умным словом "обфускация". Возможно, в [это статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122807/) вы сможете найти что-то полезное. Ну или как вариант пусть интересующую вас программу напишет студент-первокурсник. Большинство из них пишут такой код, что черт ногу сломит. Правда, за правильность реализации не поручится даже сам автор